# Wordpress Admin Login fail

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am new in wordpress please advice me on below-

My wordpress theme is working fine on localhost but when I upload my hosting server it not work correctly.

My wordpress admin panel not run it show only white blank page. but wp-login.php work fine.

My some option is not working like 'Creat page' not working.

Ohter theme is working fine. What is the problem?

You can look at : http://facebond.com/projects/wordpress/arkos/wp-admin/

Comment: Have you checked the value of `siteurl` in `wp_options`-Table? This should be `http://facebond.com/projects/wordpress/arkos/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your source with view source.There is two blank lines:

```
view-source:http://facebond.com/projects/wordpress/arkos/wp-admin/
```

There might be white space in your functions.php file of theme.please check is there any extra blank lines after the closing php tag?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would go through following steps:

Validate the server configuration

- Check the version of PHP, MySQL on your hosting server (see current WordPress [system

  requirements](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/))
- Check the wp-config.php settings (database name and user credentials)

Validate theme configuration and dependencies

- Compatibility of the used theme with the WordPress version on the hosting server
- Check the theme for referenced external widgets or plugins (e.g. a template includes some widget in the code)

For further information concerning transferring WordPress to a new server environment, consult the [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_to_a_New_Server) guide (starting with section *Moving to a New Server*)